# r merging 2 data frames that have both common and unique variables into long data

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, longitudinal

Not sure if my title conveys my question well. It will make more sense if you could read this example. I'd like to merge 2 data frames that are 2-wave longitudinal survey. Time1 data frame has more participants than Time2 data frame as not everyone returned for Time 2 survey. Some variables were measured at both times but there are others available only in each data frame. For example,

```
> d1
   ID v1 v2 T v3
1  1  A  E 1  6
2  2  B  D 1  7
3  3  C  C 1  8
4  4  D  B 1  9
5  5  E  A 1 10

> d2
  ID v1 v2 T  v4
1  1  F  A 2 100
2  3  G  B 2 101
3  5  H  C 2 102
```

I'd want to make a long dataset by merging the two, only keeping participants whose data are available at both times and keeping all variable. I want the merged data to look like d3:

```
> d3
  ID v1 v2 T v3  v4
1  1  A  E 1  6 100
2  3  C  C 1  8 101
3  5  E  A 1 10 102
4  1  F  A 2  6 100
5  3  G  B 2  8 101
6  5  H  C 2 10 102
```

The code that I used was as below.

```
d4<- merge(d1, d2, by=intersect(names(d1), names(d2)), all= TRUE)
d4<-d4[d4$ID %in% d4$ID[duplicated(d4$ID)],]

d4<- arrange(d4, T, ID)

d4[1:3, 6] <- d4[4:6, 6]
d4[4:6, 5] <- d4[1:3, 5]
```

I got what I wanted but it takes time and it is prone to errors. I think there's got to be more efficient ways to do this. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works beyond your example:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create an intermediate frame for just v3 and v4
d1a <- d1 %>% 
select(ID, v3)

d2a <- d2 %>%
select(ID, v4) %>%
merge(d1a)

d3 <- d1 %>% 
bind_rows(d2) %>% # Stack one frame on top of the other
select(-c(v3, v4)) %>% 
merge(d2a, by="ID", all.x = TRUE) %>% # Merge in to each case of those IDs
filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% # Remove rows with NAs
arrange(`T`) %>% # Arrange by T
select(ID, v1, v2, `T`, v3, v4) # Order from low to high to match your end data
```

Result:

```
  ID v1 v2 T v3  v4
1  1  A  E 1  6 100
2  3  C  C 1  8 101
3  5  E  A 1 10 102
4  1  F  A 2  6 100
5  3  G  B 2  8 101
6  5  H  C 2 10 102
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately in the actual data, I have more than hundreds of variables so I would not want to manually select variables that are unique in each dataset....any idea?

Comment: I suspected something was going on, but without a reprex example that's reflective of your full data, it's really hard to say. What's confusing most is how some variables look like they're recorded twice for the same ID (V1 and V2) while others stay constant.

Comment: Are you asking why the datas look like this? Not sure if I understand your question but I'll try to explain. Think of v1 and v2 as health-related variables and v3 and v4 are demographic variables like age or gender. I am interested in health changes so those are measured twice for the same ID but not V3 and V4.